# JMeter plugins correlation to JMeter version

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-plugins

[JMeter plugins](https://jmeter-plugins.org/) doesn't work with every JMeter version,

If my plugin doesn't work as [Soap Sampler](https://jmeter-plugins.org/) with JMeter 3.2,

Where can find correlation between JMeter plugin to JMeter version?

I didn't find any reference in [forum](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/jmeter-plugins) or documentation page.

Comment: What is the soap sampler you are using ? is it custom soap sampler ? or another one ?

Comment: custom soap sampler. but I aim for a general statement

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no compatibility matrix between jmeter-plugins and jmeter as jmeter-plugins is an aggregation of multiple plugins which:

- do not come from same source since any 3rd party project can register to be available through download manager plugin
- are not always compatible with last jmeter versions

I suggest you ask a question on jmeter plugins forum as it maybe an interesting improvement to advertise or add to descriptor the jmeter version the plugin is compatible with.

Regarding your particular plugin, one way to check is to look at pom.xml of the plugin project and potentially report a compatibility issue with jmeter 3.2