# How to upgrade Jmeter to the latest version in windows?

Tags: jmeter, performance-testing, load-testing

I've found the latest version of Jmeter is v3.3, and I was still using the v3.2 what has been clean installed several weeks before.

I haven't found the way to upgrade the latest version of Jmeter and not to clean the configuration and libs.

Comment: Why not using new version?

Comment: Download a new version then unzip it and cover all folders of previous version?

Comment: why you need old version files?

Comment: have added some ext libs, and some plugins, and also change the result report sample

Comment: so do you mean, i should clean install the latest version of Jmeter each time and also upgrade the plugin manager/plugins after the Jmeter installation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't have an upgrade process for JMeter and you don't need one,

You need to download new version of JMeter and use it.

About [plugins](https://jmeter-plugins.org/) (and extensions), it's not guarantee to work in any JMeter version, and currently there's no such [compatibility matrix](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45812802/jmeter-plugins-correlation-to-jmeter-version):

> This project is an independent set of plugins for Apache JMeter

So just update (carefully) the plugins on new version.

Comment: so what i should do is downloading a new version every time and delete the old one? then update the plugins separately?

Comment: Yes. As any software you don't have to get new version (until you do) and you can keep old version if needed